# Angular 2 call a method within ngFor

Tags: angular

How can I pass and ID from ngFor to call a method to populate my dropdown.

this is causing a parse error! (i know ngModel is not the way to go, but i just wanted to show an example)

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%; border:1px double">
     <div class="row  left" *ngFor='let controls of tabControls'>
         <div class="col-md-3 text-left" style="border:1px dotted">
             {{controls.DropDownTitle}}
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-9 text-left">
              <select [(ngModel)]="populateValues(controls.DrodownID)">
                //I will do this after populateValues which wil return an array of items
                  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
                 {{ item.name }}
                 </option>
              </select>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

output
[image]

So i have to pass dropwdownid to get all the values for Month's dropdown . then get values for years dropdown etc..

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="populateValues(controls.DrodownID)"` is invalid. You can't use two-way-binding to a method. Also binding to a control doesn't make sense. It's a weird mix of template driven and reactive forms that won't work. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: it is not dynamic form, I am just getting a dynamic number of dropdowns with a label for example : Month : Drodown. Then I am trying to pass the dropdown ID to a method to return the values for the dropdown

Comment: @rgoal Take a look at this answer I just posted, it's pretty much the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41987524/6294072

Comment: Thanks AJT, I have already constructed my object  at the webAPI level. But it is good to know how to do it this way :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "call a method to populate my dropdown".

You should do something like this:

```html
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
    {{ item.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

This is assuming you have an `items` property holding an array of `{id, name}` objects.

If you MUST, you can call a method to fetch the items directly from the template:

```html
<option *ngFor="let item of getItems()" [value]="item.id">
```

But it's usually better to call the method from your component's class and store the result in a property:

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  items: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = getItems();
  }
}
```

Comment: To fill out the why behind your answer: Due to the manner in which change checking is done using an array property results in far fewer rerenders (unless behavior changed recently) than evaluating the function every time and will have much less performance impact.

Comment: @silentsod: thanks for the info, I was actually wondering if the `getItems()` function was getting re-evaluated many times when used directly in the template.

Comment: I updated my above code, I need to pass the value to a method that will return the values ,then do the ngfor on <option>

Comment: Still, you can still call the method AND pass it a parameter from the class (vs. from the template). Where does the parameter you're passing to the method come from?

Comment: edited my code above, they came from a service. *ngFor='let controls of tabControls' return how many dropwdown i need and the title see attached image above. then i need to pass dropdown id to a service to get the values for the dropwdowns.

Comment: I'm still not following. Since the `tabControls` property exists IN YOUR CLASS, you have all dropdown ids IN YOUR CLASS, and you can fetch/prepare all the data that the template needs IN YOUR CLASS. You could store the data for all the dropdowns in a big hash/object keyed by dropdown id. Then, in the template, access it with `allDropdowns[dropdownId]`.