# Access Observable<google.maps.GeocoderResult[]> object properties in Angular2

Tags: google-maps, angular

I'm using a service with a function to geocode an address to get the latitude and longitude. This function, called getLatLon, returns an Observable of google.maps.GeocoderResult[]  and I want to create a function on a component to retrieve the latitude from that object and return it but I dont know how to access that property and return it.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
getLat(){
        let latitude: number;       
        this.geocodingService.getLatLon('My Address').forEach(                
            (results: google.maps.GeocoderResult[]) => {                                                                          
                    latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();                
            }
        return latitude;
}
```

But I'm new to angular and I dont know how to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how the JSON looks like (from google), the latitude and longitude should have the "path" like you have mentioned:

```
results[0].geometry.location.lat;  // latitude
results[0].geometry.location.lng; // longitude
```

EDIT: Since learning more about the usecase, where you are iterating over an Array and getting the latitude and longitude of each address, I would suggest you make a new Array, which makes your life easier.

So first get your array of addresses and store them somewhere. Here I just create a static array that looks like this:

```
arr = [ {address: 'address1'}, {address: 'address2'}]
```

Then moving on and looking how to get the latitudes and longitudes in the service with http-call. `x` here is the parameter for the address you need to fetch the geo data.

```
getLatLon(x) {
    return this.http.post(...)
        .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Then back to your component, where you have the array of addresses, to which you need to fetch the latitude and longitude for each address. Let's loop over each object in the array and make the call to the service. When getting the result, we then make a object with the address, latitude and longitude. You can of course replace the "address" with anything you want to store in the object. So your component would look something like this:

```
getLanLon() {
  // loop over the array of addresses that I created on top
  this.arr.forEach(x => {
    this.service.getGeo(x.address) // execute the call with address as parameter
      .subscribe(data => {
        let lati = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        let long = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        // create new object with "address", "lat" and "lon"
        let newObj = Object.assign({}, {address: x.address, lat: lati, lon: long})
          // push the newly created object to array
          this.newArr.push(newObj);
        });    
    })
  }
```

Then you can loop through your newly created array e.g like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Latitude</th>
    <th>Longitude</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let add of newArr">
    <td>{{add.address}}</td>
    <td>{{add.lat}}</td>
    <td>{{add.lon}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Below is a working sample of the app (for a limited time). Please notice that there is the same latitude and longitude values, since I'm making a call that returns the same static values. But you can see the variable "address" is different, so in your real app, you would get the correct values to each address! :)

### [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RfpbNFY9s8I4OZqvBy30?p=preview)

Comment: And if I want the method itself to return lets say the latitude.

(Sorry i can't test it right now  because of geocoder OVER_QUERY_LIMIT)

Comment: return where? In the above code you have access to both variables in the component :)

Comment: Okay, but where do you need to return it? Just call and subscribe to the latitude and longitude where it needs to be used. You do not need to "return" it anywhere?? https://plnkr.co/edit/RfpbNFY9s8I4OZqvBy30?p=preview

Comment: I want to use the method on my html like this:

*ngFor="let addres of addresses"
<h4>Latitude: getLat(address)</h4>

I'm going to loop over different addresses that's why i think i need the method itself to return the value.

Comment: No problem! I'm addicted to coding, so I'm happy to help :D